# How to achieve drill down functionality for Tibco Spotfire charts which having different data sources

Tags: tibco, spotfire

In Tibco Spotfire, I need to create a drilldown chart functionality. In which there would be 2 charts.

Chart1 has some values on x axis (x1, x2, x3…) and y axis(y1, y2, y3….). If user clicks on any bar of chart1, then chart2 would display data according to the selected bar.

My problem is- I am using different tables for both of charts. Both tables have few similar columns. 
I have tried to use detailed visualization which works good when I am using same table for both charts. But If I am using different tables for both of them then drill down functionality not works.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to get this question's answer by setting the relation between both data tables. After this, detailed visualization worked.

Comment: i'm glad agavare was able to help on this. Data relations are extremely powerful in Spotfire.